# GeoServer gives an error "A legend image format is mandatory". How can I solve this problem?

Tags: service, gis, geoserver, wms

The following error is received when sending a GetCapabilities Request to WMTS service. I couldn't make a connection between the GetCapabilities call and the error message given. How can I solve this problem?

Note: I found that it worked when I made the same request to the WMS service.

**GetCapabilities URL:**

<server_url>/gwc/service/wmts?Request=GetCapabilities

**Error Message**

400: A legend image format is mandatory

Comment: did you specify an image format?

Comment: Is such a parameter needed in a GetCapabilities request? Could you post an example in case I misunderstood?